# How to print shapes made of * in horizontal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a function that prints out shapes using *.

my code is

```
def print_saw(tooth_size, number_of_teeth):
"""Print the saw drawing"""
counter_2 = 0
while counter_2 != number_of_teeth:
    counter = 1
    while counter != tooth_size+1:
        print("*" * counter)
        counter = counter + 1
    counter_2 = counter_2 + 1
```

There is more code to that. but that's the function that prints the saw. This is printed in python like so.

```
>>> print_saw(4, 3)
*
**
***
****
*
**
***
****
*
**
***
****
```

but i want it to print horizontal. like so.

```
>>> print_saw(4, 3)
*   *   *
**  **  **
*** *** ***
************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way without using formatting:

```
def print_saw(size, number):
    for s in range(size):
        print(('*' * (s + 1) + ' ' * (size - s - 1)) * number)
```

gives:

```
print_saw(5, 3)
*    *    *    
**   **   **   
***  ***  ***  
**** **** **** 
***************
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting to set the width of each "tooth", then multiply that by the number of teeth.

```
def print_saw(tooth_height, num_teeth, tooth_width=None):
    if tooth_width is None:
        tooth_width = tooth_height  # square unless specified
    for width in range(1, tooth_height+1):
        row = "{{:<{}}}".format(tooth_width).format("*" * width)
        print(row * num_teeth)
```

DEMO:

```
In [2]: print_saw(6, 3)
*     *     *
**    **    **
***   ***   ***
****  ****  ****
***** ***** *****
******************

In [3]: print_saw(4, 6, 5)
*    *    *    *    *    *
**   **   **   **   **   **
***  ***  ***  ***  ***  ***
**** **** **** **** **** ****
```

This works by formatting twice, once to do:

```
>>> tooth_width = 6
>>> row = "{{:{}}}".format(tooth_width)
>>> row
"{:6}"
```

And the other to finish:

```
>>> width = 3
>>> row = row.format("*" * width)
>>> row = "***   "
True
```

Then multiplying that by the number of teeth you want

```
>>> num_teeth = 3
>>> row * 3
***   ***   ***
```

Answer (score 0):

The code reads as follows: "For each row, print the desired repetitions of the tooth, which consists of the fill content expanded to the tooth width."

```
def print_saw(size, reps, fill='*'):
    for row in range(1, size + 1):
        tooth = '{content:{width}}'.format(content=row * fill, width=size)
        print(reps * tooth)
```

A variant with more concatenation and less string multiplication:

```
def print_saw(size, reps, fill='*'):
    while len(fill) <= size:
        print(reps * '{0:{width}}'.format(fill, width=size))
        fill += fill[0]
```